# What is the correct way to set multiple columns in Pandas from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This must be burried somewhere in Pandas docs but I think I am so overwhelmed at this point, I can't find the right doc page. I have some code that worked with python3.9 pandas==1.4.3/numpy==1.23.1 but recently started failing with the newer version on python3.11 pandas==2.2.1/numpy==1.26.4.

I have some multi-column results in `pd.Series` that I want to set to the same number of columns inside `pd.DataFrame`. If I have code similar to:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pandas as pd


def test_assign_results() -> None:
    df = pd.DataFrame([{"is_ok": True, "failed": None, "col1": None, "col2": None}])
    m1 = MagicMock()
    m1.name = "col1_val"
    results = pd.Series([(m1, None)])
    df.loc[df["is_ok"] == 1, ["col1", "col2"]] = results.to_numpy().tolist()
    row = df.iloc[0]
    assert row["col1"].name == "col1_val"
    assert row["col2"] is None
```

The code used to work like this before but now it results in the error: [`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'`](https://gist.github.com/mrlifetime/b7b7ac1d7d4767128b286b9d06a753a2)

I suspect this code was brittle to begin with, so what would be the correct way to take 2 values and assign them to 2 columns within a DataFrame?

Comment: please paste a minimal reproducible example along with the full error traceback. hard to know what's going on without the code

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with your code, maybe your data has changed?. It's fine to assign across multiple columns, for a specific index in the way you are doing it. Are you sure that you want to assign to `pd.loc` btw?

Comment: You probably have a typo on `pd.loc` (unless you assigned a dataframe to `pd`, which would be unusual).

Comment: @jkr I put a small pytest with error log I get when I run it: https://gist.github.com/mrlifetime/b7b7ac1d7d4767128b286b9d06a753a2

Comment: Interesting. I just tested the code with venv python3.9 again and I see following deprecation warning:  VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it solves your problem but you can use .at() instead of .loc()

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"is_ok": True, "failed": None, "col1": None, "col2": None}])
>>> m1 = MagicMock()
>>> m1.name = "col1_val"
>>> results = pd.Series([(m1, None)])
>>> df
   is_ok failed  col1  col2
0   True   None  None  None
```

Your example attempts to assign m1 to df1 cell using .loc() and fails

```
>>> df.loc[0,'col1'] = m1 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1926, in _setitem_with_indexer_split_path
    if is_list_like_indexer(value) and getattr(value, "ndim", 1) > 0:
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'
```

but .at() works:

```
>>> df.at[0,'col1'] = m1
>>> df
is_ok failed                              col1  col2
0   True   None  <MagicMock id='139723045981456'>  None
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think in my case, the `loc` usage was stemmed from the fact that: i) there may be multiple rows; ii) there may be many columns in  `results`. I am still figuring out the issue but the problem ultimately stems from the fact that results is a list of tuples `[t1...tX]` where `t:=(c1...cN)` of `N` columns per row, where data types of columns may not be homogenous. Pandas is not able to expand these tuples into individual columns when types aren't easily determined, i.e. mismatched `None`, custom objects and so on.